# Wi-Fi Direct in MacOS Montain Lion

Tags: macos, installation, wifi-direct, lg

Is there a way to configure the Wifi Direct in a MacBook Pro 2011 Late? If so, which are the steps. I'm trying to configure a wifi direct connection to work in my pc but with my Smart TV Screen. My LG is a Smart Cinema 42LA6600

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you run Mountain Lion, it does not support Wi-Fi Direct.